# bootstrap carousel images overflowing the right hand grid col

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I want to keep my carousel and nav bar in the middle 75% of the screen so i laid my screen out with a grid. I cant recreate it on fiddle but if you put it into you local you'll see; screenshot: [image] see 'block 4' on top of the pic, thats where the col starts

```
  <div class="col-sm-3">col1 </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6"> Carousel goes here </div>
  <div class="col-sm-3">col3 </div>
```

The problem is that my images overflow onto the 3rd col, how can i get the carousel to stay in my middle cell/col?

full code below

```
   <body>
        <!--rows and cols structure -->
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-3">block1 </div>
          <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">     

            <!--carouselstart-->
            <div class="container page-content">
                <div class="hero row">
                    <div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
                      <!-- Indicators -->
                      <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                        <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                        <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                        <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2"></li>
                      </ol>

                      <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
                      <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
                        <div class="item active">
                          <img src="img/image1.jpg" alt="image 1 missing" title="Image 1">
                          <div class="carousel-caption">
                            <h3>caption1</h3>
                          </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="item">
                          <img src="img/image2.jpg" alt="image 2 missing" title="Image 2">
                          <div class="carousel-caption">
                            <h3>caption 2</h3>
                          </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="item">
                          <img src="img/image3.jpg" alt="image 3 missing" title="Image 3">
                          <div class="carousel-caption">
                            <h3>caption 2</h3>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>

                      <!-- Controls -->
                      <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
                      </a>
                      <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="next">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
                      </a>
                    </div>
                </div> <!--end hero -->
            </div><!--end of container-->
<!--nav bar goes here-->
          <div class="col-sm-3">block4</div>
```

UPDATE....
I used thr chrome dev tools to alter some css and found that if i set the below to 100% then it fits perfectectly. How do i do this ?
[image]

Comment: could you make a jsFiddle for it please.

Comment: I saved it in fiddle but it doesnt show same result i get in chrome or ie :( I get the pictures overflowing the grid col into the right hand side grid collum when the pictures are too big ie all the time. fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/8476/

Comment: Do you still have that problem if you shrink your browser window? The only thing I can think of is that your image height is really large and to create the correct aspect ratio the image is bleeding into the next column. Maybe try to limit the image dimensions. Bootstrap has a class img-responsive try that?

Comment: Or maybe you have some css that is overriding the css given to the images by carousel.

Comment: when i shrink it to a small size the image goes to full width as the grid responds to resize but this is to be expected. Can you give me some detail onwhat i might try for img-responsive

Comment: added img src="img/image3.jpg" alt="image 3 missing" title="Image 3" class="img-responsive"> which did nothing...

Comment: @floor - how can i check if there is overriding css?

Comment: do you have a live site link I could see? Because the fiddle seems to be working.

Comment: unfortunately not atm, i will see if i can get one in next few mins

Comment: right click on the image and click inspect element and view the css panel on the side and see if any css is causing it to bleed over. Kinda hard to explain through text.

Comment: i think its the carousel itself bleeding over as if i reduce the images by by 50% the carousel does not shrink

Comment: the carousel has a grey background and it bleeds over no matter what the picture inside it so the question becomes; how to make carousel width fit the col

Comment: It works in the fiddle so that leads me to believe you have other code (css) changing it. You should also remove the xs-col-12 from it. it will automatically go full width once it passes the sm width length

Comment: Im hitting issues getting it onto my public server. If you have bootstrap setup its a case of pasting the fiddle to it.

Comment: Found the problem css, not sure what to do about it.... see update in question

Comment: although I dont recommend altering the .container css what you could do is .container { width:100%; !important} or since you want the width to be 100% try using container-fluid instead of container.